# Is it idiomatic to use static widths in a flex container?

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm using the following CSS in order to get a quick two-column layout. The `div` on the left has a static width, and the `div` on the right fills up the remaining available space:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.left-column {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.right-column {
  width: calc(100% - 100px);
  background-color: cyan;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left-column">
    Lorum ipsum
  </div>
  <div class="right-column">
    Lorum ipsum
  </div>
</div>
```

This works the way I expect it to. I'm not using the `flex` property to accomplish this effect in either of my children `div`s, though. Is this an idiomatic, clean way to accomplish my two-column layout, or should I avoid using `display: flex` without using more flexbox features?

Comment: idiomatic ? .... if you are already using `flex` has no sense to use `calc` keep going with flex and add on your .left-column `flex:0 0 auto`

Comment: @DaniP That makes a lot of sense. Can you please add that as an answer? (And I think you mean `.right-column` instead of `.left-column`?)

Comment: Yep actually the opposite for the right will be better `flex:1 1 auto` https://jsfiddle.net/s20dyb1p/

Comment: Which properties you combine depends not only on whether it is idiomatic or not, it also affect how the fallback should be handled for browsers that doesn't support `display: flex`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The more idiomatic way to do it in flex is to use the `flex-basis` property instead of width, and you can use `flex-grow` instead of removing some width from `100%` so that something will consume the available space.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.left-column {
  /*width: 100px;*/
  background-color: red;
  flex-basis: 100px;
}

.right-column {
  /*width: calc(100% - 100px);*/
  background-color: cyan;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left-column">
    Lorum ipsum
  </div>
  <div class="right-column">
    Lorum ipsum
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to define the fixed width on your .right-column. You can make it dynamically as you are using flexbox.

```
.right-column {flex: 1;background-color: cyan;}
```

Now It is working same. But Rather than define fixed 100px {calc(100% - 100px) on here}. You define just flex: 1 and it is going to take rest of the width.

Thannks,

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/bo0ruwvm/

You can use static widths... and sometimes that is nessesary - but I would use flex-basis and grow/shrink properties to describe layout instead - and always use

`width: 100%; max-width: 400px;` etc *in general* situations for modules and layout. Static height and width is no bueno.

### markup

```
<section class='container'>
  <div class='side one'>
    one(left)
  </div>

  <div class='side two'>
    two(right)
  </div>
</section>
```

### styles

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.one {
  flex-basis: 100px; /* if possible be this width */
  /* you COULD just say width: 100px... */
  flex-shink: 0; /* if you DONT want it to ever shrink to fit */
  /* not nessesary in most cases */
  background: lightgreen;
}

.two {
  flex-grow: 1; /* fill available space */
  background: cyan;
}
```